# Android Studio error using VectorDrawable (the new Support 23.2.0 library)

Tags: android, android-support-library

When adding a VectorDrawable as the src of my ImageView using the new Support Library 23.2

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_like"
```

I get the app to compile successfully and the vector drawable to show correctly. But, Android studio showing me an error saying:

> Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag ImageView

Any advise on how to fix it? or is it just a bug and should be ignored?

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention that i have added the xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" declaration

Comment: Have you added the application namespace? In your ImageView attrs you need to add this `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: Add xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" as attribute either to your ImageView or to the Top-Level Tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like it is just a lint error that can be ignored. I have updated and have the same error, but it is working correctly.

An Android Studio update will probably fix this. I am running the latest Canary build, which contains the same error currently.

Comment: I concur. Working fine with the lint error. You might want to use tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" temporarily to ignore the error.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little worse than just an error message. In my case, it also prevents proper rendering of the image in Studio's Design mode.

**Update:** Fixed in Android Studio version 2.1